# Can we make a change to improve the tour?

Tags: discussion

I just reviewed the "Tour", and I'd like to suggest that the tour be modified by adding a section that strongly suggests to users seeking help solving issues related to a particular blender file, that they include with their questions relevant information, including version of Blender, screenshots, showing the problem, and ~.blend files, and more importantly providing new users with instructions detailing how to post the screenshot and the blend file.

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact we (David, iKlsR, and I) were just planning to start on things like this (also the FAQ, custom close reasons, etc.) with a big meta post for people to suggest ideas and help write sections :)